# adding table cells to table in a specific section in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Please if you are going to add the link of the documentation, please don't do that

I have a problem her and i don't know how to solve it and need a clear answer

I have build a table view from xcode UI and add 5 sections each section contains some cells except section2, what I want to do is to add cells to section2 in viewDidLoaded is that possible or not

this is the header file

```
@interface Menu : UITableViewController;
```

this is the implementation file

```
@implementation Menu
@synthesize drawerTableView;

- (void) viewDidLoad {

    NSDictionary *object = [drawerTableView dataSource];

    KhawaterDataManager *sharedManager = [KhawaterDataManager instance];
    CategoriesResponse *categories = [sharedManager categories];
    [categories printObject];

}

/*- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSLog(@"%d", section);

    switch (section) {
        case 1:
            return 5;
            break;

        }

    return [tableView.dataSource[section] count];
}*/

/*- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.8 green:.8 blue:1 alpha:1]];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"hello";
    return cell;
}*/


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{

    // my logic
}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the data supposed to come from that you want to show in your cells?  How do you choose which data matches a section?

Comment: @PhillipMills the data is categories, this object contains array of categories, each category contain some data, I didn't understand your second question

Comment: If I understand you, then the category at offset 2 should match the section number 2.  (Is that right?) So adding data to that category should add cells to the matching section when you reload the table.  (Actually, since you have methods commented out, I'm not sure how **any** of the sections are working.)

Comment: @PhillipMills the data in categories is not added to table datasource, I have added the data to table from xCode, and now want to append my categories inside the table, please check the image in the post

Comment: When you said, "the data is categories", I thought I understood.  Now I don't.  I give up.

Comment: @PhillipMills the table is already build using UI, and I want to add some extra calls to specific section in my table, is that possible or not ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106631/discussion-between-amira-elsayed-ismail-and-phillip-mills).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using static cells in your `UITableView`. What you can do is make use of dynamic tableview cells. You have to uncomment and use both methods to create your cell:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: Yes I am using static cell

Comment: If you want to add cells on the fly, you'll have to use dynamic cells. Static cells are used, when there is nothing to add or remove. What you should do is build the whole tableview using dynamic cells

Comment: OK Thank you very much, will try it

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions!